# Create formula fields in crystal report c# programmatically

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to add to report new formula fields programmatically (C#). But I find only how correct the existing fields. The task is to add specific fields in massive amount of reports.

Are there an other ways ?

Comment: I too have only been able to iterate through existing `reportobjects` and update them. I have not been able to add them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample:

```
FormulaFieldDefinitions definitions = MyReport.FormulaFields;
string formulaText = "IF " + MyReport.Database.Tables[1].Fields[1].Name 
+ " < 10 THEN" + MyReport.Database.Tables[1].Fields[2].Name;
definitions.Add("Test", formulaText);
MyReport.Sections[1].AddFieldObject(definitions[1], 0, 0);
```

Comment: Error 25 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormulaFieldDefinitions' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormulaFieldDefinitions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)